# CSS Background Image Property Values Explained

Tags: css, responsive-design, background-image, scaling

Can someone explain what "bottom center scroll" means in the below style

```
background: #f5f5f5 url('/img/bg.jpg') no-repeat bottom center scroll;
```

It's used here http://startbootstrap.com/templates/grayscale/ to fill the background. If I remove "bottom center scroll" the image will not scale with reduced browser size. I'd love to understand what exactly the value is doing and why it is important to how the image scales

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/colors.html (14.2)

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms530722.aspx would be helpful

Comment: Read the manual: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find below some info about that..

**Position** : Specifies the position of the background images.
**Repeat**  :Specifies how to repeat the background images.
**Attachment** : The background-attachment property sets whether a background image is fixed or scrolls with the rest of the page.

Ref for more details : http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp

Comment: @Jedda: Scroll-The background scrolls along with the element. This is by default.(If you want fixed image on screen then you can use "scroll to fixed")

Answer (score 1):

The background bottom centre property specifies the positioning area of the background images.

The background image can be placed within the content-box, padding-box, or border-box area.

Comment: @nbparmar roger that! What about "scroll"?